# Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1, or it may have already been ended

Tags: c++, ios, multithreading, uikit, objective-c++

I know this has already be asked before but unfortunately none of those answers could help me.  I have an app that executes bunch of short background tasks in different threads.  The code is mostly in C++ with ObjectiveC added to it when necessary (so the code is in .mm file).  For execution of background tasks i have roughly following C++ class with constructor and descrtuctor:

```
class BTask {
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskIden;
public:
    BTask(ExpirationHandler *h) {
        taskIden = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
            beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
            h->callback();
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskIden];
            taskIden = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
   }
   ~BTask() {
      if (taskIden != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskIden];
   }
};
```

Now, each of my tasks runs in its own thread and has the following structure:

```
void task(.....) {
    BTask btask(...);
    //....  do the work of the task
    //....  destructor of BTask will call endBackgroundTask
}
```

So when running, occasionally i get this error when endBackgroundTask is called (as in the title of the question): Can't get background task: no background task exists with identifier 1.  The error reproduces only occasionally (1 in 3-4 times) and in the beginning of the application run (so it looks like it is the first task that has the problem) and the problematic identifier somehow is always 1.

My app does not declare any background capabilities.

I m running on iPhone 6s plus simulator, but could also reproduce the problem on other simulator (iPhone 5s).

The code that implements BTask class and the tasks themselves is in static library that is linked to the application (not sure if this makes a difference).

Also note that in my test case, the app is always in the foreground.

Also, i checked that the expiration handler block is never called (which is understandable since the app does not even go into background mode).

From UIApplication reference, it seems that i m doing it correctly and it is allowed to call beginBackgroundTask... and endBackgroundTask concurrently from multiple threads to have many background tasks at any one time, as long as beginBackgroundTask... and endBackgroundTask are paired with the same identifier, which should be the case in my code.

So, so far i have no idea what the problem might be and even tend to think there may be a bug in UIKit.

Any ideas?